# Concatenate columns in rails has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

Physician has_many Patients through Appointments
Patient has_many Physicians through Appointments

How can I make the Appointment name a concatenation of Physician name and Patient name automatically in the Appointment model?

```
Physician.name = 'Joe Doctor'  
Patient.name = ' Sally Smith'  
Appointment.name = "#{Patient.name} with #{Physician.name}"
```

This is not our real world use but a simplified example.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it would be :

```
class Appointment
  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :patient

  before_create :set_default_name #optional it can be called imperatively

  def set_default_name
    if patient && doctor
      self.name= "#{patient.name} with #{doctor.name}"
    end
  end
end
```

That way whenever you add a `patient` to a `doctor.patients` it should set the appointment's name automatically:

```
@doctor.patients << @patient
@doctor.appointments.last.name # => "Dr Who with Mr Spock"
```

Comment: Approved because "Dr Who with Mr Spock" made me chuckle.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have one patient and one physician in each appointment, you can define a method in your Appointment model like:

```
def name
  self.patient.name + ' with ' + self.physician.name
end
```